# Why does K&R2 use so many global variables?

Tags: c

My teacher told me two things:

1. Avoid using global variables whenever possible.

   K&R2(The C Programming Language) is a good book for C programmer.

But when I started to read K&R2, I found that this book is almost full of global variables. Why does this book do that as a *good* book for C programmer? And if global variables are really harmful to both readability and maintenance of C programs, how can I master better practices while the famous textbook uses it so much?

Comment: I don't know that book, but global variables work okay for **small** programs such as examples. Are they showing you small programs?

Comment: Do you mean global *variables*? "Variant" is not a synonym for "variable".

Comment: Your teacher is right on both. Many times K&R makes use of globals to simplify the explanation of a particular topic or example. In practice, you will want to avoid the use of globals. Learn the topic, but understand what the topic is, and what is extraneous and included to support the example. The primary purpose for examples with globals is to avoid complicating the example with the additional code needed to properly handle passing variables as parameters (which will often include pointers or arrays of pointers which could overly complicate simple examples)

Comment: @immibis The programs in that book have at most 300 lines. Is this small enough? And how can I know how to write big program while all the examples are small programs?

Comment: @user2357112 It is "variant" and I have edited the post.

Comment: Leafing through my extremely worn out copy, I mostly see global function declarations, which is different than defining global variables.

Comment: The book is an introduction to the features and syntax of the C language. Global variables are a feature of the language, so obviously the book will discuss global variables, and show you how to use them.

Comment: K&R is a good book for learning C. But good programming practices is something different. How can an introductory book teach you good practices, if you don't even know the language. It is a good book but is not everything. If you want to learn how to manage big projects, you also need to look at other books.

Comment: Did your teacher told you: "You must do exactly as that book does, forget everything else I told you, you don't even need me" ?
It is a book to learn C programming, but the way you program is open to customization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the result of my quick scan of K&R "The C Programming Language, 2nd Edn".

Chapter 1 "A Tutorial Introduction":

- 1.1 "Hello world" — 0 globals
- 1.2 "Fahrenheit to Centigrade" — 0 globals
- 1.3 "For Loops" — 0 globals
- 1.4 "Symbolic constants" — 0 globals
- 1.5 "Character, line, word counting" — 0 globals
- 1.6 "Arrays" — 0 globals
- 1.7 "Functions" — 0 globals
- 1.8 "Arguments" — 0 globals
- 1.9 "Character arrays" — 0 globals
- 1.10 "External variables and scope" — 3 global variables in an adaptation of the code from §1.9 where the equivalent functions use no globals

Chapter 2 — Types, operators and expressions

- 2.1—2.12 — 1 definitively global variable and a number that could be local or global.

Chapter 3 — Control flow

- 3.1—3.8 — 0 globals

Chapter 4 — Functions and program structure

- 4.1 "Basics of functions" — 1 global
- 4.2 "Functions returning non-integers" — 0 globals
- 4.3 "External variables" — 4 globals
- 4.4 "Scope rules" — 1 pair of globals, several times over (repeating from 4.3)
- 4.5 "Header files" — 0 globals
- 4.6 "Static variables" — 2 file scope `static` variables (repeating from 4.3 again).
- 4.7 "Register variables" — 0 globals
- 4.8 "Block structure" — 2 globals (to make the point that local variables hide global ones)
- 4.9 "Initialization" — 0 definitively global; 5 could be global or local
- 4.10 "Recursion" — 0 globals
- 4.11 "Preprocessor" — 0 globals

Chapter 5 — Pointers and arrays

- 5.1 "Pointers and addresses" — 0 definitively global; 3 could be global or local
- 5.2 "Pointers and arguments" — 0 globals
- 5.3 "Pointers and arrays" — 0 definitively global; 2 could be global or local
- 5.4 "Address arithmetic" — 2 file scope `static`
- 5.5 "Character pointers and functions" — 0 definitively global; 2 could be global or local
- 5.6 "Pointer arrays and pointers to pointers" — 1 global
- 5.7 "Multi-dimensional arrays" — 1 global
- 5.8 "Initialization" — 0 globals
- 5.9 "Pointers vs Multi-dimensional arrays" — 0 definitively global; 4 could be global or local
- 5.10 "Command line arguments" — 0 globals
- 5.11 "Pointers to functions" — 1 global
- 5.12 "Complicated declarations" — 5 globals

Chapter 6 — Structures

- 6.1 "Basics of structures" — 0 definitively global; some could be global or local
- 6.2 "Structures and functions" — 0 definitively global; some could be global or local
- 6.3 "Arrays of structures" — 1 global; 2 could be global or local
- 6.4 "Pointers to structures" — 0 globals
- 6.5 "Self-referential structures" — 0 globals
- 6.6 "Table lookup" — 1 global
- 6.7 "Typedef" — 0 definitively global; some could be global or local
- 6.8 "Unions" — 0 definitively global; 1 could be global or local
- 6.9 "Bit-fields" — 0 globals

Chapter 7 — Input and output

- 7.1 "Standard input and output" — 0 globals
- 7.2 "Formatted output — printf" — 0 globals
- 7.3 "Variable-length argument lists" — 0 globals
- 7.4 "Formatted input — scanf" — 0 definitively global; some could be global or local
- 7.5 "File access" — 0 globals
- 7.6 "Error handling — stderr and exit" — 0 globals
- 7.7 "Line input and output" — 0 globals
- 7.8 "Miscellaneous functions" — 0 globals; 1 could be global or local

Chapter 8 — The Unix system interface

- 8.1 "File descriptors" — 0 globals
- 8.2 "Low level I/O — read and write" — 0 globals (3 function static variables)
- 8.3 "Open, creat, close, unlink" — 0 definitively global; 1 might be global but probably isn't
- 8.4 "Random access" — 0 globals
- 8.5 "Example implementation of fopen and getc" — 1 global
- 8.6 "Listing directories" — 0 globals
- 8.7 "Storage allocator" — 2 globals

In my opinion, that is not a lot globals.  Most of the 'could be global or local' variables would be local in practice, but the context isn't quite big enough to make that definitive.  In almost every case where there are globals, there are sound reasons to use those specific globals, though there are also undoubtedly alternative designs that could avoid most of those.